# How do I switch my pip downloads from the anaconda3 directory to PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

When I use pip install ____ to install packages to PyCharm it downloads them to my Anaconda3 directory. How can I change the pip install command from downnloading it to the Anaconda directory to PyCharm directory?

```
$ which pip
/anaconda3/bin/pip

$ which python
/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your project interpreter in the settings, see [PyCharm Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

At Mac it's Preferences->Project: xy -> Project Interpreter